# Route http web requests to Plex port on same server

Tags: iis

I have a blank site running in IIS, bound to port 80 HTTP traffic. This sits behind a router that port-forwards HTTP traffic to my server. Publicly I have a domain registered and use FreeDNS.Afraid.org as my dynamic DNS provider to point at my router. This is working, I can see my site publicly.

Also on my router, I am port-forwarding Plex's assigned port to the same port on my server. This is also working, I can manually find the Plex web page via `mydomain.com:<plex port>/web`.

I have a sub-domain registered that is in the format `plex.mydomain.com` where my regular domain is `www.mydomain.com`. On FreeDNS I can successfully point `plex.mydomain.com` to my blank web page.

What I am trying to do is have IIS listen for requests to `plex.mydomain.com` and route them to either `localhost:<plex port>/web` or `mydomain.com:<plex port>/web`.

I installed the URL Rewrite module and created a standard rule for redirecting based on matches with the word "plex" in it, this didn't work. I attempted to log what was happening using Failed Request Tracing; I got log files but they didn't mention any attempts to rewrite the URL.

I installed Application Request Routing, but this won't let me specify a port number. I have yet to try adding a new application to IIS that represents the Plex server.

**How can I route requests to `plex.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com:<plex port>/web`?**

I haven't got access to my server currently (but can provide the URL Rewrite configuration if necessary). Also, my experience with IIS and deployment is limited so pardon any contradictions I've made, if any.

I believe this is IIS Express on Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: And the last sentence is where it all goes wrong I'm afraid; we really only deal in server-level software here (so, IIS8 on Server 2012, not express on Windows 8). I'm going to move this over to Super User for you where you might have better luck.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Excellent thanks, wasn't sure about the exact location of this. I reviewed SuperUser beforehand but deemed the IIS part more relevant for ServerFault. My bad. To be honest, I didn't review the ServerFault help beforehand so I missed the "not about home set-ups" part.

Answer (score 0):

may be help ...

[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

[HTTP Redirects](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)

Comment: I'm not usually a fan of link answers. The first link I have exhausted, but I haven't encountered the second link. I will give that a go tonight. I originally looked for HTTP Redirect in the IIS management console, but I presume now that I haven't got that module installed / enabled.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth In the worst case, you can change the page by default, which will be engaged in forwarding the rules.